# git command to show all (lightweight) tags creation dates

Tags: git, date, tags

Is there a one liner that shows me the dates where all git lightweight tags where created ?

Something like: `git show tags --format=date` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I list all tags in my Git repository by the date they were created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269927/how-can-i-list-all-tags-in-my-git-repository-by-the-date-they-were-created)

Comment: @jleedev: I was looking for a solution for lightweight tags. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Also of possible interest for this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021599/why-does-git-for-each-ref-fail-to-sort-tags-correctly

Comment: There is no date information attached to a lightweight tag. Therefore, the accepted answer is incorrect. The dates in the output of `git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%ai %d"` are the dates of the *objects* to which the tags point, *not* the dates when the tags themselves were created.

Comment: @Jubobs strictly speaking, you are right: the correct answer is: "It is impossible to do what you want". But that is likely what the OP wanted.

Comment: See also: [How can I get a list of tags with the first line of the summary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45944271/562769)

Comment: FYI **(1.)** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6900328/52074) is for listing LIGHTWEIGHT tags by date. **(2.)** For listing ANNOTATED tag by date, [go here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6269927/52074). **(3.)** For a helpful reminder on what is the difference between Git's lightweight vs annotated tags, [go here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4971746/52074).

Answer (score 382, accepted):

I found in this [link](http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-05/msg01404.html) a solution that fits my needs:

```
git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%ai %d"
```

I've put that command in an alias in my `~/.alias`, so now everytime I run `gitshowtagbydate` I get what I needed.

Comment: It's worth piping this into sort to get a chronological order, if you're into that sort of thing.

Comment: `git log --date-order --graph --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty=format:'%ai %h %d'` :-)

Comment: git log --decorate=full --all --pretty=format:'%h %d %s %cr %ae' --abbrev-commit|grep 'refs/tags'

Comment: There is no date information attached to a lightweight tag. Therefore, this answer is incorrect. The dates in the output of `git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%ai %d"` are the dates of the *objects* to which the tags point, *not* the dates when the tags themselves were created.

Comment: In case you want to look for a specific tag, append the tag name like `git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%ai %d" | grep <tag_name>`

Comment: I set up an alias: `tags = log --date-order --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty='format:%C(green)%ad %C(red)%h %C(reset)%D' --date=short`. Sort by date, show short date, commit ID, and tag name (without parenthesis), in the colors I prefer.

Comment: @Jubobs If your tagging system performs a separate commit, like _Maven_, or if you write the new tag version manually to a version file, for instance, it _won't matter_ if it's a **lightweight tag** or an **annotated tag**. That's because the commit linked to the lightweight tag will contain the current date and committer information, anyway.

Comment: you can add ` | grep 'tag:' ` to grep only tags without branches and other stuff

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: here is the alias that can be added to ~/.gitconfig

```tag-dates = "!f(){ git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty='format:%ai %d' | sort -r; };f"```

Comment: the link is dead. i think you can remove it or update it :p

Answer (score 102):

The `git tag -l` shows a list of all tags. The `--format` argument can be used to define a custom output. For example:

```
git tag -l --format='%(refname)   %(taggerdate)'
```

Update, based on the comments below:

```
 git tag -l --sort=-creatordate --format='%(creatordate:short):  %(refname:short)'
```

Comment: Pipe delimited, iso 8601 date formatting, sorted with latest on top.  
`git tag -l --format="%(taggerdate:iso8601)|%(refname:short)" | sort -r`

Comment: `taggerdate` is not always set; try `creatordate`.

Comment: @ingyhere version was the thing I was looking for — `git tag -l --format="%(creatordate:short)|%(refname:short)" | sort -r` — [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7853670/3943954) for customising the time stamp

Comment: @revelt git >= 2.0 provides a sort param. Put a minus in to reverse the order. `git tag -l --sort=-creatordate --format='%(creatordate:short)|%(refname:short)'`

Comment: According to `git-for-each-ref` which is how the `format` flag determines and renders the fields, you can add a `*` before the fieldname so that you get at the date of the object which the tag points to. `--format='%(*creatordate)'` although I didn't see any difference when I tried this.

Comment: These methods are too slow. My pc is still computing them. The accepted answer is the way

Answer (score 5):

## You cannot

**Lightweight** (non-annotated) tags do only point to another object (like a commit, which has a date). See the one of the other answers to print these (`creatordate`).

**Annotated** tags do carry a date, an author and a message. The one of the other answers to print these (`taggerdate`).