# Get the creation date of a stash

Tags: git, git-stash

Is there a way to tell when a stash was created?

`git stash list` only lists the stashes, and `git stash show XXXXXX` shows all the files and changes, but not the **date** of the stash creation.

Answer (score 561, accepted):

Try:

```
git stash list --date=local
```

It should print something like:

```
stash@{Thu Mar 21 10:30:17 2013}: WIP on master: 2ffc05b Adding resource
```

Comment: Can I add an option somewhere in my .gitconfig to make this the default display?

Comment: @Trevoke Hm, not that I'm aware of.  Best I could find was this nabble: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-stash-list-vs-non-default-log-date-setting-td5388522.html

Comment: I prefer `git stash list --date=relative`. Worth noting is that the `--date` is coming from the `git log` command, not `stash` itself, see here for possible `--date` values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853332/git-log-date-formats

Comment: @Trevoke I added an alias `[alias]
 stashlist = "stash list --date=local"
` to my ~/.gitconfig file

Comment: `git stash list --date=short` give you date only, in fixed width YYYY-MM-DD format that is easy to visually scan.

Comment: Using this removes the ordinal number of the stash commit (e.g. `stash@{0}`). Is there a way to show the date together with the number?

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś You can use `git stash list --pretty=format:"%gd - %ci - %s"`

Answer (score 82):

You can use [`--pretty=format`](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) to achieve this. For example, this produces a stash list that includes a relative time:

```
git stash list --pretty=format:"%C(red)%h%C(reset) - %C(dim yellow)(%C(bold magenta)%gd%C(dim yellow))%C(reset) %<(70,trunc)%s %C(green)(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%C(reset)"
```

I have this set in the `[alias]` section of my `~/.gitconfig` file, so that I can bind it to a simple `sl` command:

```
[alias]
        co = checkout
        lg = log --graph --pretty=format:\"%Cred%h%Creset -%C(auto)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset\" --abbrev-commit
        rl = reflog --pretty=format:\"%Cred%h%Creset %C(auto)%gd%Creset %C(auto)%gs%C(reset) %C(green)(%cr)%C(reset) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset\" --abbrev-commit
        sl = stash list --pretty=format:\"%C(red)%h%C(reset) - %C(dim yellow)(%C(bold magenta)%gd%C(dim yellow))%C(reset) %<(70,trunc)%s %C(green)(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%C(reset)\"
```

(You can see that I also have similar markups for `log` and `reflog`)

Here's what it looks like:
[image: git stash list]

If you want to show the actual date, rather than a relative time then replace `%(cr)` with `%(ci)`.

Comment: very nice; added to mine :)

Answer (score 27):

`git show stash@{0}` also prints out the date, along with the other information.

Comment: Ah I was using the 6 character abbreviation, maybe that was the problem. I think it also threw an error when I tried that command, but I'm on windows, so that's a whole other problem :).

Comment: Ah, Windows. Trying to use git on Windows usually leads me towards wanting to defenestrate my laptop ;)

Comment: Doesn't appear to print the date with Git 2.8.3.

Comment: @ElijahLynn I don't have a 2.8.3. to test on but it prints a full commit on 2.9