# Git log - two dates in different format?

Tags: git

How can I set up date formatting in `git log` output so that dates appear in different formats?

```
hist = log --all --graph\n--pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset %ad -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'\n--abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

I want first date to be `--date=local` and last date `--date=relative`. Is it possible?

Comment: A possibility is to use `-n` and specify different date formats.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Log Date Formats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853332/git-log-date-formats).

Comment: Not duplicate, because my question was "how I can use two formates in same time" and %ad %cr is the answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

So I was wrong, `--format` can be used with the `--abbrev-commit` and `--date=relative` flags, so the problem was strictly the existence of `\n` in your command. The flags are still unnecessary, however, because their place holders are already in your command, as I've explained below.

---

It appears that the `--format` option is not compatible with the `--abbrev-commit` and `--date=relative` options. If you remove them, you'll get what you want.  You also have `\n` in your command that's not a part of the format, nor are they a legal arguments to the command, so those should be removed too:

```bash
hist = log --all --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset %ad -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'
```

In addition, the `--abbrev-commit` and `--date=relative` flags are unnecessary, since `%h` already gives you abbreviated-commits, `%ad` automatically defaults to the user's local time (if they haven't set their `log.date` config variable), and `%cr` displays the date in relative time (e.g. "7 days ago").

From [the official Kernel Git documentation for `git log`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html):

> ### [Commit Formatting](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_commit_formatting)
>
> `log.date` config variable sets a default value for log command’s `--date` option.
>
> `--date=default` shows timestamps in the original timezone (either committer’s or author’s).
>
> ## [Pretty Formats](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_pretty_formats)
>
> - `%h`: abbreviated commit hash
> - `%ad`: author date (format respects `--date=` option)
> - `%cr`: committer date, relative

Comment: Thats brilliant! :-) Just one question — how can I add custom format for first date? For example I want it to be like `01.01.13 12:08`. Upd: see your edit, going to use --date option

Comment: According to [dmedvinsky's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853332/git-log-date-formats/7853670#7853670), there is no way to do a custom date format yet. I also searched through the `git log` and `config` documentation, and I didn't see anything to that effect.

Comment: Unfortunately seems to be true

Comment: I see you stated "problem" after update, but it has nothing to do with my original question, if I use %ad and %cr even with \n, it works fine. And `\n--abbrev-commit --date=relative` works fine too. My question was "how I can use two formates in same time" and `%ad %cr` is the answer :-)