# Git alias to include time similar to magit

Tags: git, magit

I use the following alias which I like a lot:

```
git config --global alias.dag 'log --oneline --decorate --all --graph'
```

It gives me something link this:

```
* 1234  (HEAD->master, origin/master) Commit Message
```

When I use emacs magit I also get the user name and date of commit:

```
* 1234  (HEAD->master, origin/master) Commit Message    MyName   date
```

Anyone know the best way to modify the alias to provide the extra information?
It would also helped if it was column aligned like emacs does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works great, thank you guys for the great start:

```
git config --global alias.dag 'git log --pretty=format:"%C(blue)%h %C(green)%d %<(60)%Creset%s %<(20)%C(yellow)%cn %C(green)%ad" --decorate --all --graph --date=local'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

`git config --global alias.dag 'log --pretty=format:"%C(green)%h\\ %C(yellow)[%ad]%Cred%d\\ %Creset%s%Cblue\\ [%cn]" --decorate --date=local'`

This gives you a nice one-liner with the columns you wanted. Each column is also a different color for the purpose of clarity.

`--date=local` will show the current date and time, but you can use other options with the `--date` flag: `--date=(relative|local|default|iso|rfc|short|raw)`

More info on `git log --date` can be found here: [How to change git log date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853332/how-to-change-git-log-date-formats)

Comment: This is nice! I'm not getting the width to align. I get a single \ in my output.

Comment: Oh - the \ is there for styling purposes. You can delete them in the command if you want:

`git log --pretty=format:"%C(green)%h %C(yellow)[%ad]%Cred%d %Creset%s%Cblue [%cn]" --decorate --date=local
`

You can old add the `--graph` flag if you want to see additional information. You have that flag in your post.

Answer (score 1):

The ["Commit Formatting"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_formatting) section of [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) documentation has all the answers.

This command produces the output you need without colors:

```
git log --all --graph --format="%H %d %s %cn %cd"
```

The format placeholders:

- `%H` - the commit hash; use `%h` to get the abbreviated commit hash;
- `%d` - the ref names, like the `--decorate` options produce;
- `%s` - the commit subject;
- `%cn` - committer name;
- `%cd` - committer date (the format respects the `--date=` option);
  use `%cD`, `%ct`, `%cr`, `%ci`, `%cI` for other formats.

Read more about the format placeholders in the ["Pretty Formats"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) section of the documentation.