# How to get a list of different commits between two git branches?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, git-log

I want to see a list of only non-common commits between two branches.

## How can I get output like this?

Basically a `git diff -y master new-feature` summary between two branches:

```
              master                               new-feature
-------------------------------------|--------------------------------------
xxx - Jan 1st 2018 - initial commit  | xxx - Jan 1st 2018 - initial commit
xxx - Feb 1st 2018 - fix a bug       | xxx - Feb 1st 2018 - fix a bug
                                     > xxx - Mar 1st 2018 - WIP almost done
xxx - Apr 1st 2018 - fix another bug | xxx - Apr 1st 2018 - fix another bug
xxx - May 1st 2018 - fix more bugs   | xxx - May 1st 2018 - fix more bugs
                                     > xxx - Jun 1st 2018 - Ready to merge!
xxx - Jul 1st 2018 - latest patches  <
```

**Solution**: I don't know how to make heads or tails of it, but I *think* `git log --graph` accomplishes this, just with a very confusing visual style:

```
git log --left-right --graph --cherry-pick --oneline master
```

## Or this?

Better yet, `git diff -y --suppress-common-lines master new-feature` is what I really want:

```
              master                               new-feature
-------------------------------------|--------------------------------------
                                     > xxx - Mar 1st 2018 - WIP almost done
                                     > xxx - Jun 1st 2018 - Ready to merge!
xxx - Jul 1st 2018 - latest patches  <
```

**Solution:** You probably can't with git alone but, as per [@torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53109239/151312), you can get *mostly* there with `git rev-list`:

```
git rev-list --left-right master...new-feature

>eb57618eed654685a7999da847628dc5eb27313f
>0da0196ab24542a1a1697b1c0c5efeef6d09e027
>9452f57d97e5fc86e773e7a9fca488b7a0d44a0c
<4fc12fe25a127f8f0dfddf7625c22656c7b2c7c1
<9c0058dcabacfc6560f4fbaf73ea55dd70d27036
>5117fcd041793898683f9469aac00337e9fadd8b
```

## Or even just this?

And more critical than that, a `git diff --right-only master new-feature` style view would get the job done:

```
     commits only in new-feature
-------------------------------------
xxx - Mar 1st 2018 - WIP almost done
xxx - Jun 1st 2018 - Ready to merge!
```

Which, of course, could be reversed to get the opposite view `git diff --right-only new-feature master`

```
       commits only in master               
-------------------------------------
xxx - Jul 1st 2018 - latest patches
```

**Solution**: As [@brentjanderson points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53107520/151312), `git log main..new-feature` and `git cherry -v main` both do this:

```
git cherry -v main

+ c00335cd93898683f9469aafad8a8476227b117f WIP do things
+ f5c86e777d97e5f3e7a9fca488b79a0d44ac9452 WIP do more
+ 0ef6ddda576180196ab7b1c0c57eefe009e027dc Finished!
```

as well as

```
git log master..new-feature --format="%h - %ad - %s" --date=format:'%b %d %Y'

c00335cd - Jan 01 2018 - WIP do things
f5c86e77 - Feb 01 2018 - WIP do more
0ef6ddda - Mar 01 2018 - Finished!
```

P.S. I have tried `git checkout new-feature; git log --left-right --graph --cherry-pick --oneline master` before, but I can't make heads or tales (or tails) of the output. Actually, on second thought, I bet taking the output, turning it sideways, and playing it as excitebike map would make a good tale of it. Hmm...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a basic variant without fancy formatting:

`git log master..new-feature`

You can get "left side" or "right side" data by swapping the order of the branches:

`git log left-side-branch..right-side-branch`

This works with other refs (commit hashes, remote branches, tags) too.

To get the full date formatting you want:

`git log master..new-feature --format="%h - %ad - %s" --date=format:'%b %d %Y'`

This doesn't do ordinal dates (`Mar 1st 2018` is `Mar 01 2018`) because [strftime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34778736) does not support that. If that's a hard requirement, I suggest writing a batch script.

Comment: And add some hard-core ANSI escaping and coloring https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735971/151312

Answer (score 5):

> I want to see a list of only non-common commits between two branches.

This is, in set theory, the [*symmetric difference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of the set of commits reachable from branches X and Y.

This particular set grouping is so useful that it is built into the Git revisions parser, using a syntax described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), using three dots: *`X...Y`*.

> How can I get them [formatted in some particular way]

Start with `git rev-list --left-right master...new-feature`.  When using the symmetric difference notation, and adding `--left-right`, Git will list the commits along with a marker: `<` if the commits are reachable from the name on the left but not from the name on the right, or `>` if the commits are reachable from the name on the right but not from the name on the left.  Hence:

```
git rev-list --left-right master...new-feature
```

will give you:

```
<aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccdddddddddd
>eeeeeeeeeeffffffffff00000000001111111111
```

for instance, if commit `aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccdddddddddd` exists in `master` but not in `new-feature` while commit `eeeeeeeeeeffffffffff00000000001111111111` exists in `new-feature` but not in `master`.

(Options like `cherry-mark` and `--left-only` and so on modify or replace the markers to indicate which commits are patch-equivalent, if any, or omit the left or right side, or both.  For this case you do not want these.)

Having gotten the list from `git rev-list`, you can reformat it however you like.  You can use these same options with `git log` but it's generally better to collect the hash IDs first, then deal with the formatting, unless `git log`'s `--pretty=format:...` directives happen to match up with what you need (to find out, see [the **PRETTY FORMATS** section of the `git log` documentation](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_pretty_formats)).

Comment: Thank you so much. I wish I could mark multiple answers as correct because each answer answered a part of the question and I think that between the 3 I have all the knowledge that I need.

Answer (score 2):

I think running `git cherry -v master` on your `new-feature` branch should work for the right side. then do the reverse on master for the left side of your list

Comment: OOoooOooh! I like that. Do you know of any way that I can get the dates output too?

Comment: P.S. I'm didn't accept this (yet) because I want to see what other answers come up.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the dates. you might be able to combine `git log` and `git cherry` with a script or something, but i don't think `git cherry` has a built in option to output the dates

Comment: `git cherry` is specifically for finding commits that are reachable from your current branch that are or are not *patch-equivalent* to commits in some other range. It's essentially the same set as `git rev-list --right-only --cherry-mark A...B` or `git rev-list --left-only --cherry-mark A...B`, depending on which name you list for A and B, and defaulting to using `HEAD` for one of the two names. (Adding a `<limit>` parameter adds `^<limit>` to the `git rev-list`, but `git cherry` is generally more convenient as well.)

Comment: The TL;DR summary of the above is: `git cherry` is very useful, but doesn't *quite* do what @CoolAJ86 was asking for.