# Azure CLI command ( az repos pr list , etc ) that will show if commits are on source branch that have not been merged to target branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-git-deployment

Are there any Azure CLI commands that will return information about PR branches that have commits not merged into target branch. I am working through some automation and need to determine if there are any commits on a PR branch that have not been committed to the target branch.

In azure devops (ADO) when you start to create a PR, it will show you the number of files and commits like the image below. I am trying to determine if there are files or commits like the image below shows 1.

I tried these but could not see anything related in the return

azure repos pr show

Azure repos pr create

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check my answer below? Hope it could be helpful to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there seemed to be no Azure CLI command for Azure DevOps pull request to compare and list the changed files/commits from source branch pending merged to target branch.

However, you may use [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) command to check the modified files between branches. Here is a simple sample for your reference.

```
git diff --name-only main..Branch1
```

And we can use `git log` to list the new commits.

```
git log main..Branch1
```

[image]

See more discussions and samples based on different usage scenarios in the threads below.

[diff - How to get a list of different commits between two git branches? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53107027/how-to-get-a-list-of-different-commits-between-two-git-branches)

[git - How do I see the differences between two branches? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834689/how-do-i-see-the-differences-between-two-branches)

By the way, we can use this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/diffs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#between-branches) to get git diff between branches. In my case, I created a PR to merge BranchB to BranchA.

```
            "title": "PR: B->A",
            "sourceRefName": "refs/heads/BranchB",
            "targetRefName": "refs/heads/BranchA",
```

Then I called the sample API and got the response like below.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{TheRepoName}/diffs/commits?baseVersion=BranchA&targetVersion=BranchB&api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

[image]

Hope the information would help.