# How to change the git log committed log date format

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-bash

Is there any possible way to change the git log data format from "2019-08-22 06:38:34 +0000" to "20190822063834" in git log command itself or if any alternative options are great

```
git log  --pretty=format:"%ci" --decorate=full

2019-08-22 06:38:34 +0000
2019-08-22 06:38:34 +0000  
2019-08-22 06:38:33 +0000
2019-08-22 06:38:33 +0000
2019-08-22 06:38:32 +0000
2019-08-22 06:38:26 +0000

git log  --pretty=format:"%ci" --decorate=full

20190822063834
20190822063834
20190822063833
20190822063833
20190822063832
20190822063826
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a custom date format, as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34778736/6309):

```
git log --date=format:'%Y%m%d%H%M%S' --pretty=format:"%cd" --decorate=full
```

Note that I [use `%cd`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emcdem) which respects `--date=` option, not `%ci` (ISO 8601-like format).