# Extract just the 'year range' for file history in Git

Tags: git

To check that copyright history is right in files, it would be useful to get the information out of Git without needing to work through *every* commit for a file. For example

```
git log --follow -p <file-name>
```

will show the history but I need to check every commit to see which year it fell in. I can speed things up a *bit* by checking for commits from one year, but that's still awkward.

What I'd like out really is 'File was changed in 2011-2015,2017,2018,2020' or similar, but failing that a simply list of the commit dates with no other data

```
2020-02-02
2020-02-02
2018-06-06
2017-01-03
2015-04-04
...
```

would at least be easy to scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> failing that a simply list of the commit dates with no other data

You should be able to [add a simple date format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34778736/6309) to your `git log` command using [pretty format](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats):

```
git log --follow -p <file-name> --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d' --pretty=format:'%ad'
```