# How to print commit dates in %Y%m%d format in git log?

Tags: git, git-log, git-show

I am trying to print the commit date in 2021April09 format using --date=format:'%Y%b%d' but it gives me segmentation fault. Neither of below works for me even for standard formats.

`git log --pretty=format:%cd --date=format:%Y%m%d -5`

`git log --pretty=format:%cd --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d' -5`

I know I can use `git log --pretty=format:%cd --date=short` to get the shorter version but I want to use strftime format to print the abbreviated month etc

Comment: Segmentation faults are usually due to a corrupt program or memory. I don't see how a `git log` can cause a segmentation fault just by formatting a date. Unless there's something in the repo that's causing the fault. Do other `git` commands work?

Comment: What git version are you using? All commands in your post work for me.

Comment: May it be that you have to put the format in quotation marks? This answer could also help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34778736/3535187

Comment: Does `date +'%Y %b %d'` work ?

Comment: Yes, Other Git commands work. I am using Git version 2.26.

Comment: @LeGEC - How would I use that (date + ) syntax ? Can you give an example based on what I am trying ? thanks

Comment: On what OS are you running this command? And on what type of terminal are you running this from?

Comment: I meant : from bash cli, without using git, check if the standard "date" utility behaves correctly

Comment: btw : "Neither of below works for me" do you mean they also trigger a segmentation fault ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git log --pretty=format:%cd --date=format:%Y%m%d -5`

`git log --pretty=format:%cd --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d' -5`

Both of the above works fine from a CMake based command invocation but won't work for me from Git BASH on windows (MINGW32). I also tried updating Git the latest 2.31.x.

I keep getting segmentation fault. I have moved on to something else but will be looking at this thread to see if anyone else has any suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --pretty='%cd' --date=format:'%Y/%m/%d'
```

try with this