# `git tag` sorted in chronological order of the date of the commit pointed to

Tags: git, sorting

The output from `git tag` is ordered alphabetically. I would like it to be ordered chronological (the date of the commits they are assigned to, not the date on which they were created), otherwise the output should stay the same.

I’ve tried the suggestion from http://networkadmin20.blogspot.de/2010/08/howto-list-git-tags-by-date.html, but the order is still the same.

To make sure it is not an error with my repository, I tried the following with a clean repository:

```
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox % mkdir chronogit
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox % cd chronogit 
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox/chronogit % git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/soeren/Projects/sandbox/chronogit/.git/
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox/chronogit (git)-[master] % touch a
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox/chronogit (git)-[master] % git add a
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox/chronogit (git)-[master] % git commit -m 'a'
[master (root-commit) f88e0e9] a
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 a
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox/chronogit (git)-[master] % git tag 'A-first'
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox/chronogit (git)-[master] % git mv a b
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox/chronogit (git)-[master] % git commit -m 'c'
[master ecc0c08] c
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename a => b (100%)
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox/chronogit (git)-[master] % git tag 'C-second'
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox/chronogit (git)-[master] % git mv b c
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox/chronogit (git)-[master] % git commit -m 'b'
[master e72682d] b
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename b => c (100%)
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox/chronogit (git)-[master] % git tag 'B-third'
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox/chronogit (git)-[master] % git tag
A-first
B-third
C-second
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox/chronogit (git)-[master] % git for-each-ref refs/tags --sort=taggerdate --format="%(refname:short)"
A-first
B-third
C-second
```

The desired output is:

```
A-first
C-second
B-third
```

or, since inverting it shouldn’t be too hard:

```
B-third
C-second
A-first
```

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900328/git-command-to-show-all-lightweight-tags-creation-dates) is pretty similiar, so I tried the following:

```
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox/chronogit (git)-[master] % git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%ai %d"          
2013-09-06 16:08:43 +0200  (HEAD, B-third, master)
2013-09-06 16:08:21 +0200  (C-second)
2013-09-06 16:07:42 +0200  (A-first)
```

The order is fine, but now I’m fighting with the formatting…

```
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox/chronogit (git)-[master] % git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%(refname:short)"
%(refname:short)
%(refname:short)
%(refname:short)
soeren@ubuntu ~/Projects/sandbox/chronogit (git)-[master] % git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --format="%(refname:short)" 
%(refname:short)
%(refname:short)
%(refname:short)
```

Comment: seems duplicate of [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269927/how-can-i-list-all-tags-in-my-git-repository-by-the-date-they-were-created)

Comment: “annotated tags” are new for me, thats a good word to search for. But the question there asked for the order of the tags when they were created, I would like to order them accordingly to the dates of the commits they are assigned to, I will make this more clear in the question, thanks. In the comments of the question you have linked it also refers to another question, which is also similiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900328/git-command-to-show-all-lightweight-tags-creation-dates

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/22634649/6309

Comment: @Mali not of duplicate of that one because that is about the annotated tag date. But duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900328/git-command-to-show-all-lightweight-tags-creation-dates (mentioned by @wegenerd) since that it is the only sensible interpretation for lightweight tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git command to show all (lightweight) tags creation dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900328/git-command-to-show-all-lightweight-tags-creation-dates)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
git tag | xargs -I@ git log --format=format:"%ai @%n" -1 @ | sort | awk '{print $4}'
```

Comment: Impressive, though hard to remember for casual typing. What would be nice: `git tag --sort=date` or something like that.

Comment: The solution in [the thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269927/how-can-i-list-all-tags-in-my-git-repository-by-the-date-they-were-created) @Mali mentioned is better. `git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate --format=%\(refname:short\) refs/tag`

Comment: This will use commit date for sorting not the time of creation of the tag. As a result you may not get the latest tag if it was created from older commit.

Comment: @Dmitri, "lightweight" tag is simply a name for an object so it doesn't contain any other info

Comment: Great, have a lot of old ubuntu 14.04 containers with git 1.9.1 and they do not support --sort

Comment: mate your answer would be 10x better if you could explain what that magic pipe of commands does, it is awesome.

Comment: `git log --no-walk --tags` in whatever format you like.

Answer (score 71):

Just tested with git 2.8.0:

```
git tag --sort=committerdate
```

For a full list of field names you can use, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names

> For commit and tag objects, the special `creatordate` and `creator` fields will correspond to the appropriate date or name-email-date tuple from the committer or tagger fields depending on the object type. These are intended for working on a mix of annotated and lightweight tags.
>
> Fields that have name-email-date tuple as its value (`author`, `committer`, and `tagger`) can be suffixed with `name`, `email`, and `date` to extract the named component.

Comment: This is the best way, IMO. Except that you need to specify `taggerdate` instead of `commiterdate` if you want to get the chronological order of tags.

Comment: taggerdate works fine in Git 2.11.0
Is it possible to sort in inverted order though ?

Comment: If you want just the first say 3, you can always pipe it into head: `git tag --sort=committerdate | head -3`

Comment: this doesn't work if you have several tags pointed to the same commit

Comment: If you want to sort in descending order: _Prefix - to sort in descending order of the value_ (from link in answer). So i.e. `git tag --sort=-committerdate`

Comment: This works only for lightweight tags. Unfortunately it does not work with annotated tags.

Comment: Thanks @jakun that was doing my head in. I asked a separate question specifically about annotated tags here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71670977/list-all-annotated-tags-with-annotation-and-commit-date-sorted-by-commit-date

Comment: Thanks @naught101. I have asked another question for a mixture of annotated tags and lightweight tags: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71689439/2828064

Comment: It 100% printed wrong for me.  I added a tag today, added another one right after, printed with that command and my two tags are intermingled with al tags created yesterday... what in the world!!!  git version 2.32.1 (Apple Git-133)

Answer (score 29):

In git 2.3.3 I can just do this to get them sorted by date:

```
git tag --sort version:refname
```

PS: For the record, I also answered the same thing on a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414725/show-git-tags-sorted-by-date/29601177#29601177) question

Comment: This does **not** lists them sorted by date. In my repo a tag `testBranch-4` was listed after `master-10` even though testbranch is older

Comment: Well, it is supposed to do it @sydd... but it seems, there are some [known bugs with it](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/242392/focus=242822), but what they describe there doesn't seem to apply to your branch names... no idea, it works on my machine :P (just kidding, it sounds like a bug in git itself, have you tried with git 2.5?)

Comment: Surely this only works for because the chrono ordering happens to match your alpha ordering? Isn't taggerdate what is wanted?

Comment: the only thing that actually worked for me is `git tag --sort=taggerdate` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39839178/777285)

Comment: This does **not** list by date, but annotation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt-refname

Answer (score 18):

For information, to get it in reverse order, prefix it with "-"

```
git tag --sort=-taggerdate
```

Answer (score 10):

As far as I can tell, even with git 2.37+, *there is no single git command to sort tags by date of the commits they point to*, because the available sort options are:

It should be

```
git tag --sort=*committerdate
```

for correct commit chronological order for *only* [annotated tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4971746/321013).

(iff you're interested in the date the tags where pushed, use `taggerdate`here.)

and

```
git tag --sort=committerdate
```

for *only* [lightweight tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4971746/321013).

git supports a special field, [`creatordate`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref):

> For commit and tag objects, the special `creatordate` ...
> will correspond to the appropriate date ... from
> the committer or tagger fields depending on the object type. **These are
> intended for working on a mix of annotated and lightweight tags.**

This field will collapse the `committerdate` of lightweight tags and the `taggerdate` of annotated tags.

You can use

```
git tag --sort=creatordate
```

for a mix of tag types, but this will **not** sort by commit date, because it will sort the annotated tags by their creation("tagger") date, which is not the date of the commit they point to.

**To my knowledge, you need to use**:

```
git tag -l --format="%(refname:short) :: %(committerdate:iso) :: %(*committerdate:iso) ::"
```

and then sort that output with the date that is set (`committerdate` and `*committerdate` are mutually exclusive here, AFAICT).

You can also collapse the two values directly in the format expression:

```
git tag -l --format="%(refname:short) :: %(if)%(committerdate:iso)%(then)%(committerdate:iso)%(else)%(*committerdate:iso)%(end)"
```

Comment: I've found that some tags have no `taggerdate`, but they always have a `committerdate`. For `git tag --sort=-taggerdate --format "%(refname:short)  %(taggerdate:short)"` I get the tags with taggerdates at the top, and none of the rest show any dates. `committerdate` always sorts and shows dates.

Answer (score 9):

```
git log --date-order --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty=format:"%ci %d"
```

Comment: Instead of `--simplify-by-decoration` just use `--no-walk`.

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
git log --no-walk --tags --decorate --oneline
```

[Example](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb):

```
$ git log --no-walk --tags --decorate --oneline | head -n5
e214a28f (tag: v4.20.0, origin/4-stable) Release 4.20.0
519512ae (tag: v4.19.0) Release 4.19.0
a201a5ca (tag: v4.18.0) Release 4.18.0
c5037e4a (tag: v4.17.0) Release 4.17.0
9f19351d (tag: v4.16.0) Release 4.16.0
```

References:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---no-walksortedunsorted
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---tagsltpatterngt
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---decorateshortfullautono
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---oneline

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=taggerdate --format '%(refname) %(taggerdate)' refs/tags
```

It works perfectly and very fast for me.

Refer to [How can I list all tags in my Git repository by the date they were created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269927/how-can-i-list-all-tags-in-my-git-repository-by-the-date-they-were-created)

Answer (score 2):

I want to use `taggerdate`, but it does not always have a value:

```
git tag --sort=-taggerdate --format "%(refname:short)   %(taggerdate:short)" | head -5
v41     2018-11-05
v40     2018-11-05
v1      
v10     
v100
```

To support the scenario in which `taggerdate` is not set, fall back on the `creatordate` and use `sort` to sort the generated field specifically:

```
$ git tag --format '%(refname:short)    %(if)%(taggerdate)%(then)%(taggerdate:short)%(else)%(creatordate:short)%(end)' | sort -k2,2 -t$'\t' | head -5
v1  2018-05-15
v2  2018-05-15
v3  2018-05-15
v4  2018-05-24
v5  2018-06-12
```

Here's the alias:

```
[alias]
    tags = ! git tag --format '%(refname:short)\t%(if)%(taggerdate)%(then)%(taggerdate:short)%(else)%(creatordate:short)%(end)' | sort -k2,2 -t$'\t'
```

Thanks to @thomas-sibley for the solution in [this thread](https://twitter.com/theory/status/1445093920313155599).

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use `--topo-order`.

---

If you are trying to make **CHANGELOG.md**, you can use output of this command:

```
git log --pretty=format:"Commit: %an: %B %d" --tags  --topo-order > changelog.log
```

Comment: ChatGPT content is not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is NOT ChatGPT content! This is a manual on how to USE ChatGPT to make CHANGELOG.md. It was tested on my case, and I wanted to share it. Now, after my answer was edited, it doesn't make much sense.