# Show git tags sorted by date

Tags: git, git-tag

How to list **git tags in chronological order**? (recent tags first)

`git tag` only displays alphabetical order.

Comment: I know this is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18659959) but this one is much easier to read (both question and first answer).

Comment: possible duplicate of [\`git tag\` sorted in chronological order of the commit date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659959/git-tag-sorted-in-chronological-order-of-the-commit-date) I think they are close in readability, and the other is more precise, as there could be at least 3 meanings of "recent": annotated tag date, commit pointed to date, and parsed SemVer order "date"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I list all tags in my Git repository by the date they were created?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6269927/52074)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git command to show all (lightweight) tags creation dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900328/git-command-to-show-all-lightweight-tags-creation-dates).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
git tag --sort=-taggerdate
```

`taggerdate` is the appropriate field.  According to the [git tag man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag):

> Prefix `-` to sort in descending order of the value.

[`git tag`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) uses the same sorting keys as [`git-for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names), which is where the sorting keys are documented.

Comment: You can also set it as a default in your `.gitconfig`: `git config --global --add tag.sort -taggerdate`. Then you can just type `git tag` and it will be sorted by date.

Comment: correct, but not the only. the "git log --tags" sorting approach is at least as much valid and useful -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/21414726/589493

Comment: for me, when I think 'by date' I mean the committerdate. So if `--sort=taggerdate` does not do the trick, try `git tag --sort=committerdate` which for me sorted to have the tag of the most recent commit at the bottom

Answer (score 19):

Simple to remember:

```
git log --tags --decorate --simplify-by-decoration
```

Easier to read result:

```
git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%d - %cr"
```

Comment: best answer to me so far

Comment: With that second command I ended up with:
 `(tag: v1.3.1) - 9 hours ago`, `(tag: v1.3.1-rc.1) - 3 months ago`,`(tag: v1.3.0) - 4 months ago`; I only wanted the latest tag `v1.3.1` so I ended up with `git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%D" --reverse -n1  |cut -d" " -f2`

Answer (score 19):

In git 2.3.3 I can just do this to get them sorted by date:

```
git tag --sort version:refname
```

Comment: Wrong. Does not list by date, but the tag value. About `refname`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt-refname

Comment: Dito on comment above. Not everyone creates tags in alphanumeric orders :)

Answer (score 2):

Supported types when it comes to sorting with `git tag` are:

- `refname` - sorts in a lexicographic order
- `version:refname` or `v:refname` - this sorts based on versions

The solution to your problem would look like: `git tag -l --sort version:refname`

There are many more useful commands related to git tagging, be sure to check [this article](https://kolosek.com/git-tags/) out for more details.

Comment: wrong for the same reason as commented here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29601177/589493

Comment: refnames is not the tag creation date. this only works IF you created tags in alphanumeric order itfp

Answer (score 0):

`git tag --sort=-creatordate` presents the list of tags in reverse chronological based on when they were created.  That's the one I needed.  (`taggerdate` was a different order, not the one I wanted.)

Answer (score -1):

There is a nice one-liner I found that will shows date tag message, tag author and does a good job with column arrangements.

```
git for-each-ref --sort=taggerdate --format '%(tag)_,,,_%(taggerdate:raw)_,,,_%(taggername)_,,,_%(subject)' refs/tags \
 | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "_,,,_"  } ; { t=strftime("%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M",$2); printf "%-20s %-18s %-25s %s\n", t, $1, $4, $3  }'
```

Output will look like this:

```
...
2015-08-03  10:56     v1.51              Release v1.51             FirstName LastName
2015-08-10  16:12     v1.52              Release v1.52             Jane Doe
```

Credit to this [site](http://www.everythingcli.org/git-like-a-pro-sort-git-tags-by-date/)

Comment: nice oneliner he said, nice oneliner ...

Comment: see answer here on git-for-each ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/39839178/589493

Comment: you basically reimplemented "git tag --sort" (see answer above)

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
 git log --tags --decorate --simplify-by-decoration | grep ^commit|grep tag|sed -e 's/^.*: //' -e 's/)$//'
```