# Get last git tag from a given tag

Tags: git, bash, git-tag, semantic-versioning

Given a git tag (ex. v.0.1.0) I would like a bash command that will give me the previous chronological tag (ex. v.0.0.5). Here I'm using semver for version control and you can see that I can't just decrement the numbers. I need the previous last tag that was given to the repo. Thoughts?

I've tried `git describe --tags` and its giving me the last tag kindof. But nothing this specific.

Comment: Is there a problem with the `git describe --tags` output? Is it incorrect? Is it information than you need? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions out there for listing your tags in chronological order.  The one that I often use is:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=authordate --format '%(refname) %(authordate)' refs/tags
```

This works fine if all your tags are "lightweight" tags.  If all your tags are annotated tags, use `taggerdate` instead of `authordate`.  With your tags listed in chronological order, it should be easy to find the tag chronologically prior to any other given tag.

See also:

- [How can I list all tags in my Git repository by the date they were created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269927/how-can-i-list-all-tags-in-my-git-repository-by-the-date-they-were-created)
- [git command to show all (lightweight) tags creation dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900328/git-command-to-show-all-lightweight-tags-creation-dates)
- [`git tag` sorted in chronological order of the date of the commit pointed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659959/git-tag-in-chronological-order)